# XSLT - Merge, sort, dedup, order and renumber based on implicit link on consecutive rows

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT problem that I can’t fix.

I have the following XML snippet of XML:

```
<memberP>
<patent>
..

<patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
                 <fieldOfSearch>
                       <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
                              <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/18</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/120</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">A61C-8/00</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">A61C-13/38</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">A61C-5/10</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">A61C-5/12</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
                       </classificationJp>
                 </fieldOfSearch> 
</patentCitations>
...
</patent>
<patent>
..
<patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
                 <fieldOfSearch>
                       <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
                              <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/15</jppc>
                              <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/16</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
                              <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
                       </classificationJp>
                 </fieldOfSearch>
</patentCitations>
..
</patent>
</memberP>
```

What I need to do is merge, dedup, sort and renumber based on tsip:rangeFrom and tsip:rangeTo attribute values!

With the following snippet of code:

```
<xsl:key name="citedJpcc" match="memberP//patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp/jppc" use="."/>

<!-- The Wrapper-->
<xsl:template match="/">
..
..
<fieldOfSearch>    
<xsl:if test="patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp
  <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
    <xsl:variable name="classificationJppc">  -- variable holds subtree
     <xsl:for-each select="patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp/jppc">
     <xsl:sort order="descending" select="@*"/> -- Sorts on attributes
     <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('citedJpcc', .))"> -- dedupes
     <xsl:element name="jppc">
       <xsl:if test="@tsip:rangeFrom">
        <xsl:attribute name="tsip:rangeFrom">
          <xsl:value-of select="@tsip:rangeFrom"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="@tsip:rangeTo">
         <xsl:attribute name="tsip:rangeTo">
           <xsl:value-of select="@tsip:rangeTo"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:copy-of select="$classificationJppc"/>
 </fieldOfSearch>
 ..
 ..
```

This does the merge, sort and dedup such that:

```
<fieldOfSearch>
<classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">A61C-5/10</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">A61C-5/12</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">A61C-8/00</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">A61C-13/38</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/18</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/120</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/15</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/16</jppc>
 <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
 <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
</classificationJp>
</fieldOfSearch>
```

The rows with tsip:rangeFrom and tsip:rangeTo are implicitly linked together by the having the same attribute value!

What I also need to do is renumber the rows keeping the implicit link such that:

```
<fieldOfSearch>
<classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/10</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/12</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">A61C-8/00</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">A61C-13/38</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">A61C-5/18</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">A61C-5/120</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="4">A61C-5/15</jppc>
 <jppc tsip:rangeTo="4">A61C-5/16</jppc>
 <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
 <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
</classificationJp>
</fieldOfSearch>
```

But I have no idea how to do this.

Please help!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far? A [mcve] is imperative.

Comment: Hi Michael, I had tried many variations of code, from using position(), count(), combinations of these with preceding-sibling. With and without variables...etc. I just posted the bare bones for simplicity!  I'm not a XSLT specialist but a novice. Much of the code I had done but could not renumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimized example you could adapt to your needs:

**XML**

```
<memberP xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip">
  <patent>
    <patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
      <fieldOfSearch>
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/18</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/120</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">A61C-8/00</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">A61C-13/38</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">A61C-5/10</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">A61C-5/12</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
        </classificationJp>
      </fieldOfSearch>
    </patentCitations>
  </patent>
  <patent>
    <patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
      <fieldOfSearch>
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/15</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/16</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
          <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
        </classificationJp>
      </fieldOfSearch>
    </patentCitations>
  </patent>
</memberP>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="citedJpcc" match="jppc" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="memberP">
    <fieldOfSearch>    
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
            <!-- for each distinct jppc  -->
            <xsl:for-each select="patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp/jppc[generate-id()=generate-id(key('citedJpcc', .))]">
                <xsl:sort select="@tsip:rangeFrom | @tsip:rangeTo" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <!-- renumber attributes  -->
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="floor((position() + 1) div 2)" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="@tsip:rangeFrom | @tsip:rangeTo">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$i" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <!-- copy content  -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </classificationJp>
    </fieldOfSearch>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fieldOfSearch xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip">
   <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A61C-5/10</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">A61C-5/12</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">A61C-8/00</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">A61C-13/38</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">A61C-5/18</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">A61C-5/120</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="4">A61C-5/15</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="4">A61C-5/16</jppc>
      <jppc>A61C-13/39</jppc>
      <jppc>A61C-13/40</jppc>
   </classificationJp>
</fieldOfSearch>
```

---

Note: I am a little puzzled by your removal of **all** duplicates. Isn't it possible for the ranged values to have a *valid* duplicate by coincidence, for example:

```
<jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A</jppc>
<jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">B</jppc>
<jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">B</jppc>
<jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">C</jppc>
```

---

### Added:

Based on the clarifications in comments, I would suggest you try the following approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="single" match="jppc[not(@tsip:rangeFrom or @tsip:rangeTo)]" use="."/>
<xsl:key name="range" match="range" use="concat(@from, '|', @to)"/>

<xsl:template match="memberP">
    <fieldOfSearch>    
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
            <!-- handle ranges first -->
            <xsl:variable name="ranges">
                <xsl:for-each select="patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp/jppc[@tsip:rangeFrom]">
                    <range from="{.}" to="{following-sibling::jppc[1]}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- for each distinct range  -->
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($ranges)/range[generate-id()=generate-id(key('range', concat(@from, '|', @to)))]">
                <!-- reconstruct and renumber  -->
                <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="{position()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@from"/>
                </jppc>
                <jppc tsip:rangeTo="{position()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@to"/>
                </jppc>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- add singles (distinct only) -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="patent/patentCitations/fieldOfSearch/classificationJp/jppc[not(@tsip:rangeFrom or @tsip:rangeTo)][generate-id()=generate-id(key('single', .))]"/>
        </classificationJp>
    </fieldOfSearch>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<memberP xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip">
  <patent>
    <patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
      <fieldOfSearch>
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">B</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">B</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">C</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">C</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">D</jppc>
          <jppc>A</jppc>
          <jppc>B</jppc>
          <jppc>C</jppc>
        </classificationJp>
      </fieldOfSearch>
    </patentCitations>
  </patent>
  <patent>
    <patentCitations tsip:action="replace">
      <fieldOfSearch>
        <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">D</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">E</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">B</jppc>
          <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">C</jppc>
          <jppc>D</jppc>
          <jppc>B</jppc>
          <jppc>C</jppc>
        </classificationJp>
      </fieldOfSearch>
    </patentCitations>
  </patent>
</memberP>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fieldOfSearch xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip">
   <classificationJp tsip:action="replace">
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="1">A</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="1">B</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="2">B</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="2">C</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="3">C</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="3">D</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeFrom="4">D</jppc>
      <jppc tsip:rangeTo="4">E</jppc>
      <jppc>A</jppc>
      <jppc>B</jppc>
      <jppc>C</jppc>
      <jppc>D</jppc>
   </classificationJp>
</fieldOfSearch>
```

Note that this will not detect partial overlaps.

Comment: Hi Micheal, yes this is possible, ideally if a pair combination rangeFrom - rangeTo match another pair combination then the whole pair would be considered a duplicat and removed otherwise it stays.

Comment: So from your example above both pairs should stay and get renumbered!   I tried doing this initially but failed! Any ideas!?

Comment: Yes, that seems more reasonable. Before I get into this: what is the purpose of sorting the ranges by their original id, in descending order? Was that only to get the singles to appear last?

Comment: Yes, Exactly that! So the combined order is the same as the individual sets  it is merging/combining!

Comment: @madDerDog See the addition to my answer.

Comment: With the new code snippet I'm only getting the the <jppc> elements without attributes and nothing else. I made a very small change: exsl:node-set(...) to exslt:node-set(...) In the header I have: <... xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exslt" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"> I added extension-element-prefixes="exslt" as in your example!

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamMe Do note that I had to use an invented namespace declaration `xmlns:tsip="http://example.com/tsip"` in both XML and XSLT; your real namespace is surely different.

Comment: I didn't copy the namespace. Yeah I can see it's working even with my slight change to "exslt" . I must have done something wrong on my side! Thank you VERY much, you are an absolute star.